# Load user data in a new activity after selecting it from a recycler view

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My application currently shows a recycle view containing the names of users registered in the system using Firebase.
Now I need to make this recycle view clickable, click on the user's name and open a new activity showing some data of it, for example the name.

```
class PacienteAdapter(internal var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PacienteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    internal var userList: MutableList<PacienteRecycle>

    val lastItemId: String?
        get() = userList[userList.size - 1].id

    fun addAll(newUsers: List<PacienteRecycle>) {
        val init = userList.size
        userList.addAll(newUsers)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(init, newUsers.size)
    }

    init {
        this.userList = ArrayList()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.paciente_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    //context
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.textViewName.text = userList[position].nome
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        internal var textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nome) as TextView

    }

}
```

Comment: check this out https://gist.github.com/riyazMuhammad/1c7b1f9fa3065aa5a46f

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Do you have an error, what's the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this recycle view clickable & open a new activity upon a click on the user's name with showing some data of it, you can use Intent, implement an onClickListener on the name text view and put the data inside it like this:

```
class PacienteAdapter(internal var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PacienteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

internal var userList: MutableList<PacienteRecycle>

val lastItemId: String?
    get() = userList[userList.size - 1].id

fun addAll(newUsers: List<PacienteRecycle>) {
    val init = userList.size
    userList.addAll(newUsers)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(init, newUsers.size)
}

init {
    this.userList = ArrayList()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.paciente_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)
}

//context
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.textViewName.text = userList[position].nome
    holder.textViewName.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent()
            intent.setClass(context, YourActivity::class.java)

            //pass your data to the Activity
            intent.putExtra("yourDataKey1", "your-data1")
            intent.putExtra("yourDataKey2", "your-data2")
            intent.putExtra("clickedUserName", userList[position].nome)

            context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        //put the same code here to make the whole item in the view clickable
    }
}


inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    internal var textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nome) as TextView 
} }
```

Then capture the data in the other activity via Intent like this:

```
class YourActivity : Activity() {

//data
private var receivedData1: String? = ""
private var receivedData2: String? = ""
private var clickedUserName String? = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_pocmaps)

    receivedData1 = intent.extras?.getDouble("yourDataKey1")
    receivedData2 = intent.extras?.getDouble("yourDataKey2")
    clickedUserName = intent.extras?.getString("clickedUserName")
}  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I am a beginner in kotlin and I only knew the startActivity function and could not use it directly. I did not know this setClass function, now everything works, really thank you! A hug from Brazil!

Comment: Hey @fred, you're welcome.  Ask any questions on Android, Kotlin, MVVM or anything here! We're all here to help!